# How to send a value in a variable from one page to another in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am working on a phonegap application which gets an access token and stores it in a variable. I want to access that variable in another html page.

My code in page 1.

```
success: function (msg) {
    var accesstoken = msg.access_token;
    alert(accesstoken);

    //alert(msg);

    if(accesstoken.length > 2){
        window.location = 'shop_registration.html?accesstoken=' + accesstoken;                     
     }else{
        alert("Username or password incorrect")
    }
}
```

I want to access the access token variable in page 2.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What is not working in bove code ?

Comment: you can create a global variable..

Comment: The global variable would not be available after navigation to second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("accesstoken", msg.access_token);
```

They Store Your Variable 
And In Second Page Try This To Get Value

```
var data=localStorage.getItem("accesstoken");
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

> As you are sending array as a query string, Use `JSON.stringify(accesstoken)` before appending it to query string so that JSON in form of string will pe paased as an argument and while accessing it use `getParameterByName` function which will return the string:

```
var getParameterByName = function(name)
{
    name = name.trim().replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
};
var res=getParameterByName('accesstoken');//this will return you the stringified value
```

Now you have the value you have sent in form of JSON string, to convert to as array, use `JSON.parse` like this:

```
var myData=JSON.parse(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.mobile.navigate() function with latest jQuery Mobile or use $.mobile.changePage() with older jQuery Mobile to navigate page. These functions doesn't refresh whole page instead it loads content of page2 into page1. So global variables will be available after page navigaton.

Note: Only body tag of page2 will be loaded on use of changePage() or navigate() functions. So script added in head tag in page2 will be ignored. If there is script to be execute on page2 load, it will be required to add in body tag of same.